# Wizard Disabled

Tags: carto, geocoding

My wizard, infowindow, legends, etc are disabled on a basic 1 layer map I just created.

There is a separate column for latitude & longitude in the dataset.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

[image: **wizard disabled*]

Answer (score 1):

Do all your rows contain geometries? In order to detect if a dataset has geospatial data or not, right now CartoDB takes a sample of the table and checks if this small sample has data.

If you have loooots of rows in your table whose the_geom is empty, there's a chance that CartoDB is getting them and detecting an "empty" dataset (in terms of geospatial information). When there's no geospatial data, CartoDB just doesn't load the wizards.

If this is not the case, some times it has happened to me that the wizards were stuck. Refreshing the page solved that, but I think you might have already tried this.